# Subract one aggregate value from another

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm writing a query to aggregate bookings for an event, and to then split the total figure into two categories: a count of those people with an application, and a count of those without an application.

Calculating the total booking figure and the number of applicants is no problem - the code I'm using is as follows:

```
SELECT [EVENTMODULE].[DESCRIPTION] as 'Event', cast([EVENTMODULE].[STARTDATE] as date) as 'Event Date', 
SUM (case when [EVENTPLACE].[STATUS] IN ('Accepted','Attended') then 1 else 0 end) 'Total Bookings',
SUM (case when [EVENTPLACE].[STATUS] IN ('Accepted','Attended') AND [COURSEPLACE].[TYPE] = 'Application' then 1 else 0 end) 'Current Applicants' ...
```

However, I'm having problems with calculating the count of people that do not have an application (i.e. they have no application record associated with their account). I've tried using a NOT EXISTS statement, but discovered that this won't work within an aggregate statement.

So, what I'm instead trying to do is simply subtract the 'Number of Applicants' from the 'Total Bookings' figure, as this will leave me with a count of the number of non-applicants.

I've tried to simply subtract the above two outputs using the line of code below:

```
SUM ('Total Bookings' - 'Current Applicants') 'Non-Applicants'
```

But this gives me the error:

```
"Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Operand data type varchar is invalid for subtract operator."
```

I'm presuming I need to get the earlier output to cast as an Integer - please can anyone help me with the syntax?

Comment: You'll need to get rid of the quotes `''` and use brackets. SO `SUM ([Total Bookings] - [Current Applicants])`. You will have to do that in an outer query because of the aliases (so get the current query in a sub-query).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use column aliases from your calculations directly in the same query, you could use your current `SELECT` as a derived table, or a CTE, or simply derive your new calculation. Also, you should avoid using single quotes for table aliases, instead use `[]`:

```
SELECT  [EVENTMODULE].[DESCRIPTION] as [Event], 
        CAST([EVENTMODULE].[STARTDATE] as DATE) as [Event Date], 
        SUM(CASE WHEN [EVENTPLACE].[STATUS] IN ('Accepted','Attended') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [Total Bookings],
        SUM(CASE WHEN [EVENTPLACE].[STATUS] IN ('Accepted','Attended') AND [COURSEPLACE].[TYPE] = 'Application' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [Current Applicants],
        SUM(CASE WHEN [EVENTPLACE].[STATUS] IN ('Accepted','Attended') AND ISNULL([COURSEPLACE].[TYPE],'') <> 'Application' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [Non-Applicants]
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use *Square Brackets* to escape the space in column names. Single quotes will make it as string constant

```
select SUM ([Total Bookings] - [Current Applicants]) 'Non-Applicants' 
from
(
SELECT [EVENTMODULE].[DESCRIPTION] as 'Event', cast([EVENTMODULE].[STARTDATE] as date) as 'Event Date', 
SUM (case when [EVENTPLACE].[STATUS] IN ('Accepted','Attended') then 1 else 0 end) 'Total Bookings',
SUM (case when [EVENTPLACE].[STATUS] IN ('Accepted','Attended') AND [COURSEPLACE].[TYPE] = 'Application' then 1 else 0 end) 'Current Applicants' 
..
)
```

**Note :** When you are using Single quotes to escape the space in alias name it will work but it will not work when using it as column names

Comment: Thanks for your help @Prdp

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * , [Non-Applicants] = [Total Bookings] - [Current Applicants]
FROM 
(
    SELECT [EVENTMODULE].[DESCRIPTION] as 'Event', cast([EVENTMODULE].[STARTDATE] as date) as 'Event Date', 
    SUM (case when [EVENTPLACE].[STATUS] IN ('Accepted','Attended') then 1 else 0 end) 'Total Bookings',
    SUM (case when [EVENTPLACE].[STATUS] IN ('Accepted','Attended') AND [COURSEPLACE].[TYPE] = 'Application' then 1 else 0 end) 'Current Applicants' ...

) A
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
with cte as
(
SELECT [EVENTMODULE].[DESCRIPTION] as 'Event', cast([EVENTMODULE].[STARTDATE] as date) as 'Event Date', 
SUM (case when [EVENTPLACE].[STATUS] IN ('Accepted','Attended') then 1 else 0 end) 'Total Bookings',
SUM (case when [EVENTPLACE].[STATUS] IN ('Accepted','Attended') AND [COURSEPLACE].[TYPE] = 'Application' then 1 else 0 end) 
)
select Event,Event Date,Total Bookings,[Total Bookings]-[EVENTPLACE].[STATUS] AS 'Non-Applicants'
from cte
```